# How to deal with "Compile::cset" in Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile

When compiling below code

```
Compile[{{data, _Integer, 2}}, Fold[Flatten /@ Flatten[Outer[List, ##, 1], 1] &, data]]
```

I encountered error messages

> Compile::cset: Variable Compile`Variable$8984 of type {_Integer,1}
>   encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,2}.
>
> Compile::extscalar:
>   Compile`` Variable$8984=Flatten/@Flatten[Outer[List,Compile`Variable$8984,Compile ``GetElement[Compile`Variable$8985,Compile`Variable$8986],1],1]
>   cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. The result is
>   assumed to be of type Void.
>
> Compile::cset: Variable Compile`Variable$8984 of type {_Integer,1}
>   encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,2}.
>
> Compile::extscalar:
>   Compile`` Variable$8984=Flatten/@Flatten[Outer[List,Compile`Variable$8984,Compile ``GetElement[Compile`Variable$8985,Compile`Variable$8986],1],1]
>   cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. The result is
>   assumed to be of type Void.

I have no assignment in my code, Why such an error? How to deal with it and compile code successfully?

Comment: The simpler `Compile[{}, Fold[Outer[Times, ##, 1] &, {{3}}]]` already triggers `Compile::cset`.